# External Table in Azure synapse very slow performance

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, external-tables

I have a parquet file and created a new External table, but the performance is very slow as compare to a normal table in the synapse. Can you please let me know how to over come this.

Comment: are you using a serverless pool or dedicated?

Answer (score 2):

Very broad question. So I'll give broad answer:

1. Use normal table. Hard to beat performance of "normal table" with external tables. "normal table" means a table created in a Dedicated SQL pool using `CREATE TABLE`. If you're querying data from one or more tables repeatedly and each query is different (group-by, join, selected columns) then you can't get beat performance of "normal" table with external tables.
2. Understand and apply basic [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-sql-on-demand):

   - Use parquet format, which you're doing.
   - Pick right partition column and partition your data by storing partitions to different folders or file names.
   - If a query targets a single large file, you'll benefit from splitting it into multiple smaller files.
   - Try to keep your CSV (if using csv) file size between 100 MB and 10 GB.
   - Use correct data type.
   - Manually create statistics for CSV files
   - Use CETAS to enhance query performance and joins

     ...and many more.

Comment: only thing I'd add is to make sure the parquet file's storage account is in the same Azure region as the Synapse pool.

Comment: + best practises for serverless: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-sql-on-demand

Comment: @svenwildermann-msft, that's the link in "Understand and apply basic best practices: " in the answer. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Right, you already linked best practices link for Synapse Serverless (on demand). This is the one for dedicated if someone is wondering: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/best-practices-sql-pool

Answer (score 0):

a) The first step is to partition your Parquet File using a relevant partition column, such as Year, Month, and Date.

b) I recommend using a View rather than an external table as a second recommendation. External Tables don't support Partition Prunning and won't use the partition columns to eliminate unnecessary files during the read.

c) Assure that data types are enforced, and that string types are being used appropriately.

d) If possible, convert your Parquet file to Delta format. Synapse is able to read Partition columns from Delta without the need for the `filepath()` and `filename()` functions. External tables do not support Delta, only views.

Note: External tables doesn't support Parquet partition columns.

```
SELECT *,
  CAST(fct.filepath(1) AS SMALLINT) AS SalesOrderPathYear,
  CAST(fct.filepath(2) AS TINYINT) AS SalesOrderPathMonth,
  CAST(fct.filepath(3) AS DATE) AS SalesOrderPathDate
  FROM 
   OPENROWSET
   (
      BULK 'conformed/facts/factsales/*/*/*/*.parquet',
      DATA_SOURCE = 'ExternalDataSourceDataLake',
      FORMAT = 'Parquet'
   ) AS fct
  WITH
  ( 
    ColA as String(10),
    ColB as Integer,
    ColC as ... 
  )
```

Ref: https://www.serverlesssql.com/certification/mastering-dp-500-exam-querying-partitioned-sources-in-azure-storage/